# Java: Singly Linked List, instantiated 4 unique SLLists but adding a value to one list adds the same value to all lists

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm wondering if this has something to do with how I specified my Singly Linked List class, but the problem is eluding me.

Here is the Singly Linked List class:

```
class SLList {
private static Node head;
private static long size;

public SLList() {
    head = new Node(null, null);
    setSize(0);
}

static class Node {
    private Object data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Object newData, Node n) {
        data = newData;
        next = n;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setElement(Object element) {
        data = element;
    }

    public void setNext(Node newNext) {
        next = newNext;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = data + " ";
        return result;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return data;
    }
}

public Node getHead() {
    return head;
}

public long getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(long size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public void addLast(Object object) {
    Node temp = head;
    while(temp.next != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = new Node(object, null);
    size++;
}

public void remove(Object object) {
    Node pre = head;
    Node temp = head.next;
    while(temp.next != null) {
        pre = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
        if(temp.data.equals(object)) {
            pre = temp.next;
            temp = temp.next.next;
            size--;
        }
    }
}

public void printElements() {
    Node temp = head;
    if(temp.next == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty.");
    }
    else {
        while(temp.next != null) {

            temp = temp.next;
            System.out.println(temp.data);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the Set class with a method to add new values to the lists, barring duplicates already in the list:

```
public class Set {
SLinkedList aList;
SLinkedList bList;
SLinkedList cList;
SLinkedList dList;

public Set() {
    aList = new SLinkedList();
    bList = new SLinkedList();
    cList = new SLinkedList();
    dList = new SLinkedList();
}

public SLinkedList getList(char x) {
    if(x == 'a') {
        return aList;
    }
    else if(x == 'b') {
        return bList;
    }
    else if(x == 'c') {
        return cList;
    }
    else {
        return dList;
    }
}

public boolean addElement(SLinkedList list, Object newData) {
    SLinkedList.Node newNode = new SLinkedList.Node(newData, null);
    SLinkedList.Node traverseNode = list.getHead();
    while(traverseNode.getNext() != null) {
        traverseNode = traverseNode.getNext();
        if(traverseNode.getObject().equals(newNode.getObject())) {
            System.out.println("This data is already in the list.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    list.addLast(newData);
    System.out.println("Node added!");

    return true;
}

public void fillList() {
    aList.addLast("dog");
    aList.addLast(4);
    bList.addLast("test");
    System.out.println("aList: ");
    aList.printElements();
    System.out.println("bList: ");
    bList.printElements();
}

}
```

This is the output when I try to use `fillList()` to add values to the first Singly Linked List, `aList`

```
aList: 
dog 4 test
bList: 
dog 4 test
```

As you can see, adding values to `aList` adds the same values to `bList`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
private static Node head;
```

means you have *one* head for all your instances of `SLLIst`. So all `SLList` instance share the same `head`.

This should be a member of your class, and as such you'll have an instance of `head` per instance of `SLLIst`.

e.g.

```
private Node head;
```

The same applies to your `size` field. I don't think you'll need any `static` members.